# Method that takes two inputs and splits queue

Tags: java, methods, data-structures, queue

I want to call this method to send a portion of elements in the queue to the back of the queue, but when I call it in main it just shows me an empty queue.
Is there a better way to do this.

```
//m: the number of customers initially in line
//n: the portion of m that will be sent to the back of the queue today
public T lastCustomer(int m, int n)
{
int count;
ListNode<T> processed = new ListNode<T>(front.data);
while(rear!=null) 
{ 
  for(count=0;count< n;count++) 
{ 
  T extracted = dequeue(); 
      boolean check = enqueue(extracted); 
 if(check == true) continue; 
else break; 
}

processed.data = dequeue();
m--;
n=m/2; 
}


return processed.data;

}
```

Comment: what Class do you actually extending?

Comment: It is my own implemented version of a linked list queue so none

Comment: what is `while(rear!=null) `?

Comment: `ListNode` is your class as well?

Comment: Some one said I should have that there since I'm en queuing from the back and yes ListNode is one of my classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason you get empty Queue is

```
while(rear!=null)
```

combined with:

```
processed.data = dequeue();
```

you dequeue as long, as your `rear` is `null` and the Queue is empty.
for your task you actually don't need `m`:

```
public T lastCustomer(int n){
    T result = null;
    while(n > 0){ 
        result = dequeue(); 
        enqueue(result);//you probably don't need to check the result(depends on your implementation)
        n--;
    }
    return result
}
```

this should do the job

EDIT: forgot `n--;`

EDIT: rationalized variables